# Include the same file twice with a variable in Jinja, but render different content based on the variables I set

Tags: html, include, jinja2, markdown

I have set the content of a variable to the following HTML text in the `shared_file.md` file:

```
{% setvar random_text %}
{% if random_variable %}
<p>Hello, World!</p>
{% else %}
<p>Hello, Earth!</p>
{% endif %}
{% endsetvar %}
```

As you can notice, the file contains an *if-else* statement that renders a different `<p>` depending if `random_variable` is `true` or not. What I'm currently doing in a markdown file is the following:

```
<<shared_file.md>>

{% setvar random_variable %}true{% endsetvar %}
{{random_text}}

{% setvar random_variable %}false{% endsetvar %}
{{random_text}}
```

As you might understand, I'd like to render the following text:

```
<p>Hello, World!</p>
<p>Hello, Earth!</p>
```

However, the result I'm getting is instead the following one:

```
<p>Hello, Earth!</p>
<p>Hello, Earth!</p>
```

I infer that this issue might come from the fact that the variable is only imported once. I tried including the `shared_file.md` file twice but I'm getting an error. Do you know what how to unblock me on this issue?

Thanks in advance for your replies!